# Sticky Component inside scrollview

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a a sticky component like this app

http://www.screencapture.ru/file/E88F08Fc

Deals, Products, Events tabs/segmentControl are actually start from bottom and as you scroll when you hit bottom of the header it stops and start stick while the content keep scrolled

this is my code

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView 
                style={styles.container}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                onScroll={
                    Animated.event(
                        [{nativeEvent:{contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}]
                    )
                }
            >
                {this._renderScrollViewContent()}
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.stickyStuff}></View>
            <Animated.View
                style={[styles.header, {height: headerHeight}]}
            >
                <Animated.Image
                    source={require('../../assets/images/pvj.jpg')}
                    style={[styles.backgroundImage, {opacity: imageOpacity}]}
                />
                <Animated.View style={[styles.bar, {transform: [{translateY: titleTranslateY}, {translateX: titleTranslateX}]}]}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>PARIS VAN JAVA</Text>
                </Animated.View>

            </Animated.View>
        </View>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @ChrisGeirman sorry to make you confuse, cause i still havent got any reputation so i cant embed images need to screen cap every movement to demonstrate the UX so here step by step the ux i need to expect 1. http://www.screencapture.ru/file/1609269e 2. http://www.screencapture.ru/file/fEA8377B 3.http://www.screencapture.ru/file/651a7f98 4.http://www.screencapture.ru/file/8871a435 as you see the tab (Deals, Products, Events) start from middle of the screen as you scroll up it will start to stick at header

Comment: Strange that SO would restrict new users from adding screenshots. I don't remember that. I understand now. Will think on it, but have you looked at [LayoutAnimation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thank you for answering my first question. I found it how to do it now. So basically what I do is I cheat on F8App code where they fallback from F8Scrolling native module if it is not available to this:

```
if (!NativeModules.F8Scrolling) {
  var distance = EMPTY_CELL_HEIGHT - this.state.stickyHeaderHeight;
  var translateY = 0; this.state.anim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, distance],
    outputRange: [distance, 0],
    extrapolateRight: 'clamp',
  });
  transform = [{translateY}];
}
```

which gives the idea of animating my sticky view so here is i ended up

```
const stickySegmentControlX = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, STICKY_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
    outputRange: [INIT_STICKY_HEADER, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
})

...

    return(
    ....
     <Animated.View ref="stickyHeader" style={[styles.stickyStuff, {top: stickySegmentControlX}]}>
       <Text>Go Stick</Text>
     </Animated.View>
    ....
   );
```

so basically what I've done is animating the top position of an {position: 'absolute'}'s view while as the value of output range is between bottom position to the height of my header (so it'll stop right below my header) and the input range is between 0 and the difference of the top position and the header height. Eventually, the animation will feel natural as you scroll the scrollview.

There you go a sticky header custom view. Here is the result:

[image]

If you feel my answer is confusing, its better you heading to janic duplessis Medium post:
[React Native ScrollView animated header](https://medium.com/@janicduplessis/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e#.4m2xjqd23)

Comment: I go through your medium blog, i did not see sticky header there. I need sticky header (one of multiple header in list), can you tell way?

Comment: @bondan-herumurti can you please eloborate whats the distance variable in inputRange

Comment: Would you mind providing the source code for this please?

Answer (score 127):

It is very simple with ScrollView component. There is already something called "stickyHeaderIndices" which takes the index of child to make sticky.In following code, content inside renderComponent2 stays sticky when you scroll.

```
<ScrollView
      stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 >
  {this.renderComponent1()}
  {this.renderComponent2()}
  {this.renderComponent3()}
 </ScrollView>
```

Refer: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#stickyheaderindices

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: doesn't let the content below the sticky index scroll. once the sticky header is stuck in position, the only way you can scroll is down...

Comment: Refer should be https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#stickyheaderindices

Answer (score 11):

**This is very easy you just need to know the index component that you want it to sticky during scrolling inside a scrollview component**. Here is an example:

```
 <ScrollView
      style={styles.screen}
      stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
 >
     <View><Text>Hello1</Text></View>
     <View><Text>Hello2</Text></View>
     <View><Text>Hello3</Text></View>
 </ScrollView>
```

**So when scrolling Hello1 text will sticky to the top of the ScrollView**

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you'll actually want to just position your element outside of the `ScrollView` and use `position: absolute` to achieve a sticky effect. This is often more straightforward, if the element is consistently supposed to stick at the top or bottom, and doesn't involve any styling issues, which `stickyHeaderIndices` can sometimes cause.

```js
<MyComponent style={{position: absolute;}}/> // will be sticky to top
<ScrollView> 
    // scrolling components
</ScrollView>
<OtherComponent /> // functionally sticky to bottom; looks like content is scrolling behind it, even though the scrollview just stops before it.
```

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to have a sticky spacer over the status bar, you can use an intermediate element as a placeholder.

```
      const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

      return (<ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}>
        <HeroImage />

        <View style={{ paddingTop: insets.top, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />

        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          .... Your components
        </View>
      </ScrollView>)
```

The second view is what pads the top.

Answer (score -1):

This can prove useful

```
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ScrollView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.handleCoroutineException

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
class StickyViewHistory(val stickyViewInflateListener: StickyViewInflateListener, val scrollView: ScrollView) {


    interface StickyViewInflateListener {
        fun inflate(view : View)
        fun getHeaderViews() : List<View>
        fun removeSticky()
        fun getStickyHolderView() : View
        fun getStickyLayout() : View
    }

    var currentVisibleHeader : ViewOverLapState? = null
    private var isStickyVisible = false

    init {
        scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { view: View, i: Int, newScrollY: Int, i2: Int, oldScrollY: Int ->
             val overlapStates = getOverlappStates()
             val numberOfHeadersAboveScroll = overlapStates.filter { it == ViewOverLapState.IS_ABOVE }.count()
             //If all of the headers are either visible or below the screen, we remove the sticky
             if(numberOfHeadersAboveScroll == 0){
                 if(isStickyVisible == true){
                   removeSticky()
                 }
             }
             else {
                 if(newScrollY < oldScrollY){
                     displayHeaderWhenScrollingDown(overlapStates)
                 }
                 else {
                     displayHeaderWhileScrollingUp(overlapStates)
                 }

             }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Assumes there is atleast one header view which has scrolled above screen
     */
    fun displayHeaderWhileScrollingUp(overlapStates : List<ViewOverLapState>){
        val mostRecentAboveHeader = getMostRecentAboveHeader(overlapStates)
        val highestVisibleHeader = getHighestVisibleHeader(overlapStates)

        //If there is a header on screen which is just about to overlap the current sticky layout we remove the Sticky altogether
        highestVisibleHeader?.let {
            if(isOverlappingCurrentStickyLayout(it.view)){
                removeSticky()
                return
            }
        }


        // If the most recent header that has scrolled above screen is the current sticky,
        // we dont do anything since its already being displayed as sticky
        if(currentVisibleHeader != null && currentVisibleHeader!!.view == mostRecentAboveHeader.view){
            //Do nothing
        }
        else {
            //We sticky the most recent header which has scrolled above screen
            setSticky(mostRecentAboveHeader)
        }

        isStickyVisible = true
    }


    fun displayHeaderWhenScrollingDown(overlapStates : List<ViewOverLapState>){
        currentVisibleHeader?.let { cvh ->
            val highestVisibleHeader = getHighestVisibleHeader(overlapStates)
            highestVisibleHeader?.let { hvh ->
                if(isOverlappingCurrentStickyLayout(hvh.view)){
                    removeSticky()
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        if(currentVisibleHeader == null){
            val mostRecentAboveHeader = getMostRecentAboveHeader(overlapStates)
            setSticky(mostRecentAboveHeader)
        }
    }


    /**
     * Checks if a view is overlapping with any part of the current sticky layout
     */
    fun isOverlappingCurrentStickyLayout(childView: View) : Boolean{
        val locationOfSticky = IntArray(2)
        stickyViewInflateListener.getStickyLayout().getLocationOnScreen(locationOfSticky)
        val childLocation = IntArray(2)
        childView.getLocationOnScreen(childLocation)
        val locationOfScrollView = IntArray(2)
        scrollView.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfScrollView)
        if(childLocation[1] <= locationOfSticky[1]+stickyViewInflateListener.getStickyLayout().height &&
                childLocation[1] >= locationOfScrollView[1]){
            return true
        }

        return false
    }


    /**
     * Get the headerview which most recently scrolled above screen
     */
    fun getMostRecentAboveHeader(overlapStates : List<ViewOverLapState>) : ViewOverLapState {
        val aboveViews = overlapStates.filter { it == ViewOverLapState.IS_ABOVE }
        var lowestAboveView : ViewOverLapState? = null
        var highestYCooridnatesoFar = Int.MIN_VALUE
        aboveViews.forEach {
            val locationOnScreen = IntArray(2)
            it.view.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen)
            if(locationOnScreen[1] > highestYCooridnatesoFar){
                lowestAboveView = it
                highestYCooridnatesoFar = locationOnScreen[1]
            }
        }
        return lowestAboveView!!
    }

    /**
     * Highest here does not mean the highest [y] value but its position on the screen, so lower y means higher
     */
    fun getHighestVisibleHeader(overlapStates: List<ViewOverLapState>) : ViewOverLapState? {
        val insideViews = overlapStates.filter { it == ViewOverLapState.IS_INSIDE }
        var highestInsideView : ViewOverLapState? = null
        var lowestYCordinatesoFar = Int.MAX_VALUE
        insideViews.forEach {
            val locationOnScreen = IntArray(2)
            it.view.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen)
            if(locationOnScreen[1] < lowestYCordinatesoFar){
                highestInsideView = it
                lowestYCordinatesoFar = locationOnScreen[1]
            }
        }
        return highestInsideView
    }


    fun getOverlappStates() : List<ViewOverLapState>{
        return stickyViewInflateListener.getHeaderViews()
            .map {
                getOverlapState(scrollView,it)
            }
    }

    /**
     * For all of the view headers, get their overlap state with the scroll view
     */
    fun getOverlapState(parentView : View, childView : View) : ViewOverLapState{
        val scrollViewLocation = IntArray(2)
        parentView.getLocationOnScreen(scrollViewLocation)

        val childLocation = IntArray(2)
        childView.getLocationOnScreen(childLocation)

        if(childLocation[1] < scrollViewLocation[1]){
            return ViewOverLapState.IS_ABOVE.apply { view = childView }
        }
        else if(childLocation[1] > (scrollViewLocation[1]+parentView.height)){
            return ViewOverLapState.IS_BELOW.apply { view =childView }
        }
        else {
            return ViewOverLapState.IS_INSIDE.apply { view = childView }
        }
    }



    fun setSticky(viewOverLapState: ViewOverLapState){
        stickyViewInflateListener.inflate(viewOverLapState.view)
        currentVisibleHeader = viewOverLapState
        isStickyVisible = true
    }

    fun removeSticky(){
        currentVisibleHeader = null
        stickyViewInflateListener.removeSticky()
        isStickyVisible = false
    }

    enum class ViewOverLapState(val text : String) {
        IS_INSIDE("inside"),IS_ABOVE("above"),IS_BELOW("below");
        lateinit var view : View
    }
}
```